# Socket client не получает строку с сервера

Tags: java, сокет, websocket

Простейший сервер-клиент на сокетах, работает в одностороннем порядке. Сервер посылает строку по нажатию кнопки, клиент получает, сохраняет, по нажатию кнопки выводит.

Код сервера:

```
package ru.quwantoq.server; 

import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent; 
import java.awt.event.ActionListener; 
import java.io.*; 
import java.net.ServerSocket; 
import java.net.Socket; 


public class Main { 
static Socket socket; 
static ServerSocket serverSocket; 

public static void sendMessage(Socket socket, String msg) { 
try { 

OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream(); 
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os); 
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw); 
bw.write(msg); 
bw.flush(); 
System.out.println("The message \"" + msg + "\" was succsesfully sent!"); 
} catch (Exception e) { 
System.out.println("Can't send a message"); 
System.out.println(e); 
} 

} 

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
int port = 1451; 
try { 
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port); 
System.out.println("New server was started on port: " + port); 
} catch (IOException e) { 

System.out.println("Unable to start the server"); 
System.exit(0); 
} 


ActionListener e = new ActionListener() { 
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 

Main.sendMessage(socket, "Test message to client123"); 

} 
}; 

JFrame frame = new JFrame("Server"); 
frame.setVisible(true); 
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
frame.setBounds(200, 200, 200, 200); 

JButton sendButton = new JButton("Send"); 
frame.add(sendButton); 
frame.pack(); 
sendButton.addActionListener(e); 
while (true) { 

socket = serverSocket.accept(); 
if (socket != null) { 
System.out.println("New connection"); 
} 
} 

} 

}
```

Код клиента:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.print.Printable;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.rmi.server.ExportException;


public class Main {
    static String allhistory;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Client");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setBounds(200, 200, 200, 200);
        JButton refreshbutton = new JButton("Refresh");
        frame.add(refreshbutton);
        refreshbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                System.out.println(allhistory);
            }
        });
        Socket s = null;

        try {
            InetAddress inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.249");
            s = new Socket(inetAddress, 1451);
            System.out.println("Connected to server");


        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR");
            System.out.println(e);
            System.exit(0);
        }

        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.println("In catching");
                InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                allhistory = "";
                allhistory += br.readLine();
                //br.readLine nichego ne poluchaet

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                System.exit(0);
            }


        }
    }

}
```

По логам WireSharka пакеты до клиента доходят, следовательно проблема в клиенте.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если внимательно почитать документацию [BufferedReader.readLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) то можно найти:

> Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one
>    of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return
>    followed immediately by a linefeed.

Т.е. `BufferedReader` ожидает конца строки, чтобы вернуть данные по методу `readLine()`, а вы не посылаете этого символа. Добавьте на сервере к посылаемой строке `\n` и всё будет работать.